# Column operations with pandas DataFrame objects with non-unique indices

Tags: pandas

I have a strange problem and I finally managed to reproduce it.

Here is the pickle file: https://cloudup.com/cr71lzPei-D

```
data = pickle.load(open('temp/toy.pkl', 'rb'))
print(data.shape)
delta = data.date1 - data.date2
print(delta.shape)

print(sys.version)
print(pd.__version__)
```

And here is the output:

```
(99, 2)
(239,)
3.4.0 (default, Apr  9 2014, 11:51:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)]
'0.14.1'
```

As you may see, `delta` is much bigger than than the original table. It looks like the calculation performs a full outer join on the two columns using the indices, which is somewhat unexpected. How and when this behaviour occurs and is there a way to prevent it?

**Original message**

I couldn't reproduce it with a toy problem, so I will try to explain it in words.

I have a Pandas `DataFrame`  with about 100K lines, about 20 columns and a non-unique index. When I try to calculate the difference between two columns I get a results that is more than 5 times longer than the original table. If, instead of `table.column1 - table.column2` I do `numpy.array(table.column1) - numpy.array(table.column2)` I get the expected result.

It looks like the calculation performs a full outer join on the two columns using the indices, but when I tried to reproduce this behaviour using toy problems I never got similar result.

I also tested whether `NaN`s affect this: there are `NaN`s in one of the columns in my original data, but toy problems with `NaN`s worked as expected, so I have to rule out `NaN`s.

How and when this behaviour occurs and is there a simpler way (compared to converting to `numpy.array`) to prevent it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have any `NaN` values? This doesn't explain everything but it would be useful to see if any of your columns have `NaN` values, in the past I have found that merging on columns that contained `NaN` values to cause extra rows to be added so I always checked and dropped them. Anyway worth checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in < 0.15.0, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8364). Only shows up when you try to do datetime ops on a non-unique indexer. Here's an example of the correct behavior. This will appear in 0.15.0, sched for 2nd week of Oct 2014.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({'A' : np.arange(5), 'B' : np.arange(1,6)},index=[2,2,3,3,4])

In [2]: df.B-df.A
Out[2]: 
2    1
2    1
3    1
3    1
4    1
dtype: int64

In [3]: df = DataFrame({'A' : date_range('20130101',periods=5), 'B' : date_range('20130101 09:00:00', periods=5)},index=[2,2,3,3,4])

In [4]: df.B-df.A
Out[4]: 
2   09:00:00
2   09:00:00
3   09:00:00
3   09:00:00
4   09:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I have finally managed to reproduce the error (see the edited question).  As you may see, my Pandas version is pretty recent.

Comment: ok this is indeed different for datetimes ops (as opposed to pure integer ops)....let me see

Comment: closed here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8364; if was joining on equal (but non-unique indexers), and not checking. The non-datetime ops take a different path.